# ImageMagick: convert png fail via PHP and works via bash shell

Tags: php, apache2, imagemagick, mamp

I've got a very weird bug which I've yet to find a solution. **UPDATE** see solution below

What I am trying to do is convert a full size picture into a 160x120 thumbnail. It works great with jpg and jpeg files of any size, but not with png.

ImageMagick command:

```
/opt/local/bin/convert '/WEBSERVER/images/img_0003-192-10.png' -thumbnail x320 -resize '320x<' -resize 50% -gravity center -crop 160x120+0+0 +repage -quality 91 '/WEBSERVER/thumbs/small_img_0003-192-10.png'
```

PHP function (shortened)

```
...
$cmd = "/opt/local/bin/convert '/WEBSERVER/images/img_0003-192-10.png' -thumbnail x320 -resize '320x<' -resize 50% -gravity center -crop 160x120+0+0 +repage -quality 91 '/WEBSERVER/thumbs/small_img_0003-192-10.png'";
exec($cmd, $output, $retval);
$errors += $retval;
if ($errors > 0) {
    die(print_r($output));
}
```

When this function runs $retval equal 1 which means the convert command failed (thumbnail isn't created).

This is where it gets interesting, if I run the exact same command in my shell, it works.

```
wedbook:~ wedix$ /opt/local/bin/convert '/WEBSERVER/images/img_0003-192-10.png' -thumbnail x320 -resize '320x<' -resize 50% -gravity center -crop 160x120+0+0 +repage -quality 91 '/WEBSERVER/thumbs/small_img_0003-192-10.png'
wedbook:~ wedix$
```

I've tried using different PHP function such as system, passthru but it didn't work. I thought maybe someone here knew the solution.

I'm using

1. `MAMP 1.7.2`

   - `Apache/2.0.59`
   - `PHP/5.2.6`

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

I updated the following dependencies

1. `libpng from 1.2.35 to 1.2.37`
2. `libiconv from 1.12_2 to 1.13_0`
3. `ImageMagick 6.5.2-4_1 to 6.5.2-9_0`

However, it did not fix my problem.

**2nd UPDATE**

I finally found something that might help, when the function runs this is what gets printed in the Apache logs:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
  Referenced from: /opt/local/bin/convert
  Reason: Incompatible library version: convert requires version 8.0.0 or later, but libiconv.2.dylib provides version 7.0.0
```

**3rd UPDATE**

libiconv.2.dylib is version 8.0.0...

```
bash-3.2$ otool -L /opt/local/lib/libiconv.2.dylib 
/opt/local/lib/libiconv.2.dylib:
    /opt/local/lib/libiconv.2.dylib (compatibility version 8.0.0, current version 8.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 111.1.4)
```

**4th UPDATE**

Problem was related to MAMP, see solution below

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solved it!

It turns out the environement variable `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` wasn't set properly.

Mac OS X Leopard comes with libiconv 7.0.0 but convert requires 8.0.0 (see 2nd UPDATE above)

```
bash-3.2$ otool -L /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib 
/usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib:
    /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 7.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 111.1.1)
```

ImageMagick and all dependencies was installed with MacPorts under `/opt/local`. This requires to manually add the path /opt/local/lib to `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

If I add the path `/opt/local/lib` to `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` in the Mac OS X Leopard `apachectl` envvars file `/usr/sbin/envvars` it doesn't work. Why? It's because I don't use apache from Mac OS X Leopard, I use MAMP.

MAMP **has its own** apachectl script **and it's own** envvars file.

I added the path `/opt/local/lib` to `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` in the MAMP `apachectl` envvars file `/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/envvars`

```
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="/opt/local/lib:/Applications/MAMP/Library/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH"
```

Now my PNG thumbnails are being generated and no errors are generated in the apache error log!

I hope this will help someone and next time I'll remember to check every logs files before asking for help!

Phil

Comment: Was going to suggest this was a Leopard-specific issue after reading about the COMMAND_MODE issue. Nice work :)

Comment: man this is not working for me and I am pulling my hair here... any other instruction not mentioned here you might have done?

Comment: hi... I could make a "hello world" like `exec("convert logo: logo.gif")` and it works fine... however, a more complex convert will work in shell but not in exec(): `/opt/local/bin/convert -size 758x185 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/recetas/img/photo/old.tmp -crop 470x185+142+0!   -quality 100 +profile "*" /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/recetas/img/photo/new.jpg`... I am creating logo.gif in the same dir as old.tmp so it is not a matter of paths (besides, the thing works if I copy/paste the command in bash or sh. The error in apache (no php errors) is `sh: command_here: No such file or directory`

Comment: for the record: seems the `escapeshellarg()` function does something with the paths causing ImageMagick not to work. I had never used that before but saw it as a recommendation in php.net so went ahead with that and have just wasted threee whole days debugging this freaking thing... oh well

Comment: Hey you rock! This helped me out. I installed imagick using homebrew and with the new version of OSX (Lion), X11 is already installed. I had a problem where i included /usr/local/lib but I still could not use png format. So I had to include /usr/X11/lib. Now it works!

Answer (score 5):

My path was /opt/local/bin, but even adding that to DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH didn't work. Finally when I changed just plain ole PATH, it worked via PHP.

;Did not work...

;DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="/opt/local/bin:/Applications/MAMP/Library/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH"

;export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH

; This works!

export PATH="$PATH:/opt/local/bin"

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you! This helped me solve the problem :)

Comment: Thanks! I know that these "thank you" comments are discouraged, but this ended a long, confusing battle for me.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the user running the php code has the same permissions on the files and directories.

Comment: Yes, both images and thumbs folder are also world-writable.

Answer (score 0):

These should be obvious, but make sure you check things like PHP safe mode, open_basedir, and whether `exec` has been disabled.

Comment: They aren't disable, I was able to generate thumbnails from JPG and JPEG files but not from PNG files. See solution below